# Timezone fun with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, dst, cairo

After DST change in Cairo, we realized-to our dismay-that the opening times don't appear correctly to the user and are actually one hour after what they ought to be. I document here our research in to the issue in case anyone has had the displeasure of dealing with the same symptoms.

This took quite a bit of debugging because the behavior of the moment library appears to be different in a web browser than inside ReactNative (possibly also we had different versions).

Mainly the problem had to do with how our code works. I am not clear on why we keep a timestamp to represent opening times instead of just the hour number. This appears to be the main failure in our design. The problem with storing a generic time signature is that it will store with it the UTC + DST offset for your timezone and there lies the culprit.

So say we have an opening hour of 9:00+002 which is meant to represent 11:00 in our local time zone but the question here is, well, if you switch now to DST with an offset of +3, is this the correct Offset?...and the answer in our case was a resounding NO!

This info is communicated from the server end indicating to the client that the branch will open at 09:00+2 however, today, a month after the government re-instated DST (we were blissfully unaware of these issues for 8 or so beautiful years), the client end says ok, this is really 09:00 in UTC and now lets add +3 because this is the DST offset to UTC, and lo and behold our shop which in winter had opened at 9:00 is now opening at 10:00... JOY!

So the proper fix for this is to ensure you don't store generic times as timestamps in your rails application. And if you have made this mistake a workaround that may help is:

```
offset = Time.current.strftime("%:z")   # Get current timezone offset

json.opening_hours branch.opening_hours.select { |o| o.day == DateTime.current.wday }.map { |o|
 { 
  opens_at: o.opens_at.iso8601.to_s.gsub(/\+\d\d:\d\d/,offset)
  ...
   }
}
```

Happy to hear your suggestions and any discussion on what the best approach is for dealing with opening times.

Edit 1:

Further to the above, you may need to handle time computations but modify your offset to whatever the system now is configured to. Using a helper function like `change_to_current_tz` can bridge this issue as well. As [Les Nightingail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451893/les-nightingill) points out, the better solution is to re-design your app to store hours as an integer and work with these instead:

```
def change_to_current_tz(time)
    offset = Time.current.strftime("%:z")   # Get current timezone offset
    now = DateTime.current
    # make sure we are checking against today in specific
    # discard the date portion and put in today's date
    # IF THIS IS NOT DESIRED THEN UPDATE THIS PORTION FOR YOUR CODE
    Time.new(
      now.year, now.month, now.day,
      time.hour, time.min, time.sec,
      offset
    ) 
  end
```

Comment: isn't it easier to migrate your database to store the opening time as an hour integer rather than write code to work around a poor prior design decision?

Comment: @LesNightingill Yes, fixing the design is ultimately the best solution. However, I'm nervous about going full out with migration from the get go and preferred a patch that would get users up and running right away until we had a better handle on what else is affected.

Comment: Is there an actual *question* here?  If so, please edit your post to state what the question is.  You can always answer your own question if you like.  If you're just looking for a code review, then a more appropriate site is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint , the question is mainly if there is a better approach and whether this is a proper analysis of the situation.